# protocol handler using dev_add_pack consumes cpu

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I wrote a kernel module and used dev_add_pack to get all the incoming packets.
According to given filter rules, if packet matches, I am forwarding it to user space.

When I am loading this kernel module and send udp traffic using sipp,
ksoftirqd process appears and starts consume cpu. (I am testing this by top command)

is there any way to save cpu ?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you use ETH_P_ALL type to register your packet_type structure to protocol stack. And I think your packet_type->func is the bottleneck, which maybe itself consumes lots of cpu, or it  break the existing protocol stack model and triggers other existing packet_type functions to consumes cpu. So the only way to save cpu is to optimize you packet_type->func. If your function is too complicated, you should consider to spit the function to several parts, use the simple part as the packet_type->func which runs in ksoftirqd context, while the complicated parts should be put to other kernel thread context(you can create new thread in your kernel module if needed).

Comment: Yes, tian absolutely right you are 
The below is my handler struct and function

`static struct packet_type my_proto = {
        .type = __constant_htons(ETH_P_ALL),
        .func = my_packet_handler,
};`


The "my_packet_handler" function is simple though.
I am filtering packets by its src address & on match I am putting that packet into work_queue.

The issue is when I am loading the module and start the udp traffic, 
ksoftirqd appears and starts consuming cpu, even if there is no rule to match.

What shoud I do ?

Comment: Hi John: You know fd= socket(PF_PACKET, mode, htons(ETH_P_ALL)) also trigger kernel codes to call dev_add_pack() to add ETH_P_ALL packet_type, which func is packet_rcv_spkt(). And it works fine. So I think your feature can use this alternative approach and codes are most in user space. Or you insist on your approach, you can compare my_packet_handler with packet_rcv_spkt() to see the difference between them.